# Too many _coef values for LogisticRegression in Pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, sklearn-pandas, coefficients

I'm making use of the sklearn-pandas [DataFrameMapper](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/sklearn-pandas) in a sklearn Pipeline. In order to evaluate feature contribution in a feature union pipeline, I like to measure the coefficients of the estimator (Logistic Regression). For the following code example, three text content columns `a, b` and `c` are vectorised and selected for `X_train`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
np.random.seed(1)

data = pd.read_csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/WZHwqLWr')
#data.columns

X = data.copy()
y = data.result
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

mapper = DataFrameMapper([
        ('a', CountVectorizer()),
        ('b', CountVectorizer()),
        ('c', CountVectorizer())
])

pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('featurize', mapper),
        ('clf', LogisticRegression(random_state=1))
        ])

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_test)

print(abs(pipeline.named_steps['clf'].coef_))
#array([[0.3567311 , 0.3567311 , 0.46215153, 0.10542043, 0.3567311 ,
#        0.46215153, 0.46215153, 0.3567311 , 0.3567311 , 0.3567311 ,
#        0.3567311 , 0.46215153, 0.46215153, 0.3567311 , 0.46215153,
#        0.3567311 , 0.3567311 , 0.3567311 , 0.3567311 , 0.46215153,
#        0.46215153, 0.46215153, 0.3567311 , 0.3567311 ]])

print(len(pipeline.named_steps['clf'].coef_[0]))
#24
```

Unlike a normal analysis of multiple features, which usually returns coefficients of equal length to the number of features, the DataFrameMapper returns a larger matrix of coefficients.

a) How is a total of 24 coefficients in the upper case explained? 
b) What's the best method to access the [coef_](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) value of each feature ("a","b","c")?

Desired output:

```
a: coef_score (float)
b: coef_score (float)
c: coef_score (float)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although your initial dataframe did indeed only contain columns for your three features `a`, `b`, and `c`, the Pandas `DataFrameMapper()` class applied SKlearn's `CountVectorizer()` to the respective word corpuses of each column a, b, and c. This resulted in the creation of a grand total of 24 features, which were then passed to your `LogisticRegression()` classifier. This is why you got an unlabeled list of 24 values when you tried to access the classifier's `.coef_` attribute.

However, it's pretty straightforward to match each of those 24 `coeff_` scores with the original column (`a`, `b`, or `c`) that they come from, and then calculate the average coefficient score for each column. Here's how we'd do it:

The original dataframe looks like this:

```
             a                   b                c   result
2   here we go   hello here we are   this is a test        0
73  here we go   hello here we are   this is a test        0
...
```

And if we run the following line, we can see a list of all the 24 features that were created by the `DataFrameMapper`/`CountVectorizer()` used in your `mapper` object:

```
pipeline.named_steps['featurize'].transformed_names_

['a_another',
 'a_example',
 'a_go',
 'a_here',
 'a_is',
 'a_we',
 'b_are',
 'b_column',
 'b_content',
 'b_every',
 'b_has',
 'b_hello',
 'b_here',
 'b_text',
 'b_we',
 'c_can',
 'c_deal',
 'c_feature',
 'c_how',
 'c_is',
 'c_test',
 'c_this',
 'c_union',
 'c_with']

len(pipeline.named_steps['featurize'].transformed_names_)

24
```

Now, here's how we'd calculate the average coef scores for the three sets of features that came from `a`/`b`/`c` columns:

```
col_names = list(data.drop(['result'], axis=1).columns.values)
vect_feats = pipeline.named_steps['featurize'].transformed_names_
clf_coef_scores = abs(pipeline.named_steps['clf'].coef_)

def get_avg_coef_scores(col_names, vect_feats, clf_coef_scores):
    scores = {}
    start_pos = 0
    for n in col_names:
        num_vect_feats = len([i for i in vect_feats if i[0] == n])
        end_pos = start_pos + num_vect_feats
        scores[n + '_avg_coef_score'] = np.mean(clf_coef_scores[0][start_pos:end_pos])
        start_pos = end_pos
    return scores
```

If we call the function we just wrote, we get the following output:

```
get_avg_coef_scores(col_names, vect_feats, clf_coef_scores)

{'a_avg_coef_score': 0.3499861323284858,
 'b_avg_coef_score': 0.40358462487685853,
 'c_avg_coef_score': 0.3918712435073411}
```

If we want to verify which of the 24 coeff scores belongs to each created feature, we can use the following dictionary comprehension:

```
{key:clf_coef_scores[0][i] for i, key in enumerate(vect_feats)}

{'a_another': 0.3567310993987888,
 'a_example': 0.3567310993987888,
 'a_go': 0.4621515317244458,
 'a_here': 0.10542043232565701,
 'a_is': 0.3567310993987888,
 'a_we': 0.4621515317244458,
 'b_are': 0.4621515317244458,
 'b_column': 0.3567310993987888,
 'b_content': 0.3567310993987888,
 'b_every': 0.3567310993987888,
 'b_has': 0.3567310993987888,
 'b_hello': 0.4621515317244458,
 'b_here': 0.4621515317244458,
 'b_text': 0.3567310993987888,
 'b_we': 0.4621515317244458,
 'c_can': 0.3567310993987888,
 'c_deal': 0.3567310993987888,
 'c_feature': 0.3567310993987888,
 'c_how': 0.3567310993987888,
 'c_is': 0.4621515317244458,
 'c_test': 0.4621515317244458,
 'c_this': 0.4621515317244458,
 'c_union': 0.3567310993987888,
 'c_with': 0.3567310993987888}
```

Comment: I have just seen that you added `start_pos = end_pos` to the function. That makes sense and is indeed crucial for the loop.

Comment: Thanks and yeah, it ensures we're using the right coeff values to compute the avg coeffs for a, b, and c columns.

Comment: Hi @James Dellinger, one last question: This doesn't work when the DataFrameMapper has features tht aren't count vectorized, right? I mean for example: 'mapper = DataFrameMapper([
        ('a', CountVectorizer()),
        ('b', CountVectorizer()),
        ('c', None)
])' It looks like 'clf_coef_scores' only outputs one value per feature column.

Answer (score 5):

After recovering the fitted `DataFrameMapper` from the `Pipeline`, you can access its contents using the `.features` method. That makes possible to iterate through the `CountVectorizer` functions that you have used to transform strings into one-hot-encoded variables. Each CountVecotrizer has a `.vocabulary_` method that tells you exactly what column what string is representing.

You can therefore just pull out in sequence each `CountVectorizer` in the `DataFrameMapper` and for each of them, extract in sequence the string representing each columns in the input matrix. This will allow you to have a sequence exactly representing the labels of your coefficients.

Based on your example, this snippet code should do what you need and that I described in detail above (please warn me if you get any error, I will correct it based on your feedback):

```
# recover the fitted mapper
fitted_mapper = pipeline.named_steps['featurize'] 

mapped_labels = list()
# iterate through the CountVectorizers
for label, fun in fitted_mapper.features:
    # Iterate through the sorted vocabulary
    for level, _ in sorted(fun.vocabulary_.items()):
        mapped_labels.append(label+'_'+level)

# the ordered sequence of vectorized strings
print(mapped_labels)

# pick up the coefficients
coefs = pipeline.named_steps['clf'].coef_[0]

# pair mapped labels and coefs and print them
for label, coef in zip(mapped_labels, coefs):
    print("%s:%0.5f" % (label, coef))
```

Comment: Thank you! As I applied the code, it seems that it gives the scores for words, but not  the scores for a feature column (a,b,c)? However, if possible, it would also be an interesting side-question, how I could select specific words from the example above.

Comment: After encoding the levels as single variables by CountVectorizer, there is no coefficient for features columns anymore, but there are coefficients for the newly created features which are binary variables, each one representing a single word. You can still gather all the binary variables that were derived from one of the original features, but there is no meaningful way to represent them as a single coefficient. Even if you can average the words' coefficients related to a feature, or just sum them up, or even compute the difference between the highest and the lowest value, that's not useful .

Comment: is there also a way to work with a list, instead of a dict? At the end, I need to normalise all scores, so that they are relative. Also, as the columns are scaled differently, is there a way to correct so that the coefficients are comparable?

Comment: In order to normalize all the scores, you have to put in your Pipeline, between 'featurize' and 'clf' a sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler function, so you will statistically standardize the different word count variables and have their coefficients comparable. Another way is to just have sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer work with the parameter binary=True, in this case you won't have any counting of occurences but just a pure binary for each word.